# 機械学習のRNNについて勉強してみています。エラーメッセージについて教えてください。

Tags: python, anaconda, keras, pycharm

機械学習初心者です。
機械学習のRNNについて勉強してみています。

```
history = ins_model.fit(x, t, epochs=20, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1)
```

上記コードを追加し実行したところPyCharmに以下のメッセージがでています。
これはどういった意味のことでしょうか？
一応モデル学習は行われているようです。
対処対応の方法などご教授いただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

```
2020-03-10 08:31:22.291990: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/dense_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/dense_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.294990: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.296991: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.307992: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.308492: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/dense_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/dense_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.309492: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.310992: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-10 08:31:22.313493: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_function_library_runtime.cc:697] Ignoring multi-device function optimization failure: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

ーーーーーーー
Windows7 64bit
Anaconda3 2019.10
PyCharm 2019.3
keras 2.3.1
tensorflow 2.1

Answer (score 0):

これは、グラフに循環依存関係があるためです。計算グラフは線形でなければなりません。コードを確認し、循環依存関係を削除して線形にします。
[このリンクも参照してください](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)